# 500 error from rest API batch endpoint when inserting node with label

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to insert a node with a label using the rest API's batch endpoint.

The URL I'm hitting is: `http://localhost:7474/db/data/batch`

The payload is

```
[{"body": {"ConceptId": "78890", "Name": "This is a node"}, "to": "/node", "method": "POST"}, {"body": "Moo", "to": "{0}/labels", "method": "POST"}]
```

The 500 response body is:

```
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body><p><pre>Illegal character in path at index 2: ./{0}/labels</pre></p><p><pre>IllegalArgumentException
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:859)
    at java.net.URI.resolve(URI.java:1043)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.calculateTargetUri(BatchOperations.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.performRequest(BatchOperations.java:193)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.parseAndPerform(BatchOperations.java:171)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.NonStreamingBatchOperations.performBatchJobs(NonStreamingBatchOperations.java:48)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService.batchProcess(BatchOperationService.java:126)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService.performBatchOperations(BatchOperationService.java:76)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)</pre></p></body></html>
```

So far as I can tell, the syntax is correct, according to sources such as the [Neo4j documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-batch-ops.html) and this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132132/neo4j-v2-0-0-m3-rest-api-batch-insert).

Can anyone help? I'm using 2.1.2, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David,

You are missing the job id for the first action.  Try this:

```
[{"id":0, "body": {"ConceptId": "78890", "Name": "This is a node"}, "to": "/node", "method": "POST"}, {"body": "Moo", "to": "{0}/labels", "method": "POST"}]
```

Without the "id":0 on the first action, the {0} in the second action can't be dereferenced.

Grace and peace,

Jim